# How to add up to/calculate with every value in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this in `PHP`: `$prices = array(12.4,18.5,23,43.54);`
I want to calculate every single value in this array, no matter how much there are.

Let's say I want to add `+3` to every value.

Means, change

`$prices = array(12.4,18.5,23,43.54);`

to

`$prices = array(15.4,21.5,26,46.54);`

I found out there should be a way to do this with `array_map` but I don't know it and don't know how to use it. I tried several ways but none works. Is `array_map` the right to do what I want to reach? Or, how can I do this?

Comment: and have you **tried anything** yourself so far? for example a *loop* going over every element of the array?

Comment: Yes, array_map. However, simply use a for loop.

Comment: You can use `array_map` or simple `foreach`. Just give it a try and come back to us. We will help you out!

Comment: array_walk, array_map, foreach, while, or even a for or doWhile loop would work.  Personally I would use array_map.

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<?php
$prices = array(12.4,18.5,23,43.54);
foreach ($prices as &$value){
    $value = $value + 3;
}
print_r($prices);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like

```
$prices = array(12.4,18.5,23,43.54);
$res = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val + 3;
},$prices);
```